# About Removing the automatically installed packages

Tags: upgrade

When I tried to full-upgrade the packages in Ubuntu 17.10 using `sudo apt full-upgrade`, the following message appeared in the terminal. I would like to know if it would be proper to remove them or keep it without affecting the functioning.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  caja-common libmarco-private1 libmate-desktop-2-17 libmate-menu2
  libmate-slab0 libmate-window-settings1 libmatekbd-common libmatekbd4
  libmatemixer-common libmatemixer0 marco-common mate-control-center-common
  mate-desktop mate-desktop-common mate-icon-theme mate-menus
  mate-settings-daemon mate-settings-daemon-common mate-user-guide
  python-mate-menu
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2):

those packages all belong to the Mate desktop. I assume since you upgraded to 17.10 that it installed the gnome-desktop.

Unless you want to keep the mate desktop, they can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it really depends on if you use these packages or if any of your services use these packages. I would say it would be okay to go ahead and remove them since they are no longer needed nor required in the newer updates of Ubuntu. But to be safe, just mark them down somewhere so if you ever need to install them again you can simply just run `sudo apt install ...` then add that you marked down....

Answer (score 0):

None of both options should affect functionality.

`apt` automatically resolves dependencies for installed and removed packages.

So it wouldn't mark those packages as `no longer required` if any other package on your system would still rely on them. As you can see it only informs you for `automatically installed` packages so if you installed packages manually you need they wouldn't be listed their neither.

In short:
Usually you always can run `sudo apt autoremove` in order to free disk space without loosing functionality but be careful what is removed.
In your case it's removing the mate-desktop. If you want to keep it I would actually suggest anyway let them be removed and later install it again after you fully upgraded.